# Enable Windows Firewall (with Advanced Security) logging

Tags: c#, winapi, vbscript, windows-firewall, audit-logging

Which is the equivalent of:

```
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile logging filename %systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log
```

in C/C++ and VBScript ?

I found nothing in official: [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Note:
I am interested only in enabling/disabling logging, not in changing the log filename.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about C/C++, but in VBScript you'd simply shell out to run the `netsh` commandline:

```vbs
logfile = "%systemroot%\system32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log"

Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "netsh advfirewall set currentprofile logging filename " & qq(logfile)
```